# Missing angular-ui-router states in AngularJS unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-ui-router

I am trying to test the routes defined for the angular-ui-router of my AngularJS application. The test is using a karma / jasmine setup. I am injecting the `$state` service in the test in order to check if all relevant states have been defined. However, the `$state` service only lists a single (empty) state. Here is how the module setup and the test setup look like:

**Module Definition:**

```
angular.module('module', ['ui.router'])

.config(function($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('state01', {
            url: '/state01'
        })
        .state('state02', {
            url: '/state02'
        });
});
```

**Test Definition:**

```
describe('module', function() {
    var $state;

    beforeEach(module('module'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$state_) {
        $state = _$state_;
    }));

    describe('module config', function() {
        it('should test stuff...', function() {
            console.log($state.get());
            // prints: [Object{name: '', url: '^', views: null, abstract: true}]
        });
    });
});
```

Any ideas, why the `$state` service might be missing the router state definitions?

Comment: are you sure you have `v0.3.0` of `ui-router`?

Comment: I am using `v0.2.15` of `ui.router`. Isn't this the most recent one?

Comment: please do look at API page https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategetstatename

Comment: Ah, I see. As far as I can tell, the `get()` call should work in `v0.2.15` (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/0.2.15/src/state.js#L1375). What would be an alternative approach?